# Novice: How to use Promises in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am working AWS async lambda function which writes data to a DynamoDB table for my Alexa smart home skill.  The problem I am having is that it doesn't write the database using async.  However, I convert it to synchronous, it will work correctly.  I do not have much experience with Javascript and zero experience with using promises.  I would like to know what's wrong with my code/promise.

Thank you for you help or suggestion!

```
exports.handler =  async function (event, context) {

    // Dump the request for logging - check the CloudWatch logs
    console.log("index.handler request  -----");
    sendToDynamo("Signal-01","powerState","ON");

}

function sendToDynamo(endpoint,state,value) {
  console.log("send to dynamo start")

  var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
                  apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
                  region: 'us-east-1'})

  var params = {
      TableName: "TestDB",
      Item: {
          'ItemId':{
            S: endpoint  
          } ,
          'State':{
            S: state  
          } ,
          'Value':{
            S: value  
          } 
      }
  };

  var putObjectPromise = ddb.putItem(params).promise();

    putObjectPromise.then(function(data) {
      console.log('*** Success ***');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
exports.handler =  async function (event, context) {

    // Dump the request for logging - check the CloudWatch logs
    console.log("index.handler request  -----");
    let data = await sendToDynamo("Signal-01","powerState","ON").catch(console.log);
    console.log('*** Success ***');
}

function sendToDynamo(endpoint,state,value) {
  console.log("send to dynamo start")

  var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
                  apiVersion: '2012-08-10',
                  region: 'us-east-1'})

  var params = {
      TableName: "TestDB",
      Item: {
          'ItemId':{
            S: endpoint  
          } ,
          'State':{
            S: state  
          } ,
          'Value':{
            S: value  
          } 
      }
  };

  return ddb.putItem(params).promise();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing my issue!  Question: How can I tell if the promise was successful or reject?  Examine 'data'?

Comment: so you will see in the `catch` i pass in a callback function value being `console.log`. if you wanted to tell if you were successful or not, you would implement some better  code in the `catch` block then rethrow (if that was how you wanted to handle the error)

Comment: if you would rather not use `await`, you can pretty much copy and paste your `.then().catch()` block on the `sendToDynamo()` call. All await does is unwrap the promise.

Comment: I would like to try it without the await.  So, like this?      let data = sendToDynamo("Signal-01","powerState","ON");
    
   data.then(function(data) {
      console.log('*** Success ***');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });

Comment: yea...looks right, though the formatting in comments is clunky.